# Linking records on foreign slow in LINQ query

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I'm experiencing extremely slow query execution when linking records on foreign keys. For instance I have a "GraphPoint" class which holds DateTime/double pairs. This query executes in under a second for 150000 records (dummy number for value):

```
var data = from x in dataContext.Table1
           select(new GraphPoint(x.Time, 100));

List<GraphPoint> graphPoints = new List<GraphPoint>(data);
```

When I try to link a second table on a foreign key the execution slows to a crawl. After an hour I gave up on this query:

```
var data = from x in dataContext.Table1
           select(new GraphPoint(x.Time, x.Table2.First().Value));

List<GraphPoint> graphPoints = new List<GraphPoint>(data);
```

Why is it so slow compared to the first one?

I've tried using a precompiled query but that didn't help either.

Comment: Is that Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL? You have both tags in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [DataContext.Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) property to see the exact SQL that is being generated, then investigate if there is anything you can do at the database end to optimize the query performance (such as adding indexes).

Comment: I'm using a SDF database for this particular query and I can't work out how to index a column that is not a primary key.

Comment: @BoroDrummer In the Server Explorer, expand the node representing your table, right-click on the *Indexes* sub-node and pick *Create Index*.

Comment: That worked! Got the query time down to about 20 seconds now. Still seems fairly slow, but it is just about acceptable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Loading the second table with table1 might improve performance here,

Try

```
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Table1>(x => x.Table2);
dataContext.LoadOptions = dlo;
```

Linq is translating it to dynamic sql and getting each record for related table record in table1 dynamically which is slowing down the performance.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming this block of code should just precede the query? If so, my query is still taking over 10 mins (I abort it after that time).

Comment: then it might be a case with the sql db, Is your primary and foreign keys properly indexed?!

Comment: Foreign keys are not. I'll try and figure out how to do that tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Adding an index to the foreign key made all the difference. However, loading the second table with table1 didn't improve things. Thanks for the idea though!